# What are the pros/cons of using noexcept specifiers at Embedded Systems?

Tags: c++, exception, embedded, noexcept

Is there any advantage of using the `noexcept` specifiers of C++ while coding for an embedded system?

- Does it make the binary smaller?
- Does it make the code run faster?
- How does it differ from the GCC's `-fno-exceptions` flag? Does using that flag marks every function as `noexcept`?

Comment: 6 questions here.  Perhaps narrow the list?

Comment: What have you tried?  What have you measured?  Consider that every Embedded System is different or unique.  Some things that work with one system may not work or have the same impact on another system.  Time to have the compiler print out the assembly language.  Time to break out the oscilloscope on some test points and measure the efficiency.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews You are right! I should've done them all.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Aren't they closely related to each other?

Comment: Just recently, I fiddled with `noexcept` (to become familiar with it) and noticed that 1.) `noexcept` doesn't prevent that you can call a possibly throwing function (i.e. no diagnostic). 2.) Wrapping function calls in the body of a `noexcept` function with a `try {` and `} catch (...) { }` (if you are paranoid like me) might be recognized and optimized by the compiler. [Demo on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/oaE855bvf) (Remove the `noexcept` from `something()` to see the difference.)